# A question involving positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let say I have a vector of suitable dimension as $x$ where $x^Tx<1$ and each element of this vector is bounded above and below with +1, -1 respectively.

Now there is a PD matrix as $\Sigma$.

With above input, does below relation always hold $x^T \Sigma x<1$?

Any insight will be very helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 100 & 0\\0 & 100\end{pmatrix}$, this would fail. So I think we should assume further suitable assumptions on $\Sigma$.

Comment: If the diagonal elements of $\Sigma$ are 1 then will that condition hold?

Comment: If you have additional conditions, please add them to your question. Also, for a numerically falsifiable hypothesis, please exercise due diligence and carry out a computer experiment to see if the hypothesis is supported by numerical evidence.